# Extremely low loss on training, prediction is always the same value

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.keras

### Issue summary

Training my data results in very strange verbose:

```
loss: -35657827.5218 - accuracy: 0.5018 - categorical_accuracy: 1.0000
```

Expected prediction result is -1, 0 or 1. But the trained model only outputs 0

### Data

I prepared two million rows of data with the following structure.
These are all the features. They are float values between -1 and 1.

```
[
    "relative_price_week",
    "relative_price_day",
    "relative_price_hour",
    "relative_price_fivemin",
    "relative_volume_week",
    "relative_volume_day",
    "relative_volume_hour",
    "swing_month",
    "swing_week",
    "swing_day",
    "swing_hour",
    "swing_fivemin",
]
```

And the output is expected to be one of three options, -1, 0 or 1.

[image: Visualized data]

### Model

```
input = Input(shape=(12,))
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(input)
x = Dense(32, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(16, activation='relu')(x)
output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=output)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy', 'categorical_accuracy'])
model.fit(train_features, train_labels, batch_size=100000, epochs=10)
```

Previous versions of the model would also result in nonsensical data. By which i mean, it would output only one of several fixed outputs.
One version would have three output columns `['buy_conf', 'hold_conf', 'sell_conf']`, each representing a value between 0 and 1.
Unfortunately, this too would result in strange outputs with accuracy being 0.9 and a similar negative loss. The trained output for this model would also put one of very few options as the output for each column.

### Questions

- Do you see anything immediately obviously wrong with this code?
- Can you suggest an approach to find a way of solving this issue?

Comment: I have no idea what your data looks like, though it looks like half your data carries state 0. The categorical accuracy does not have an interpretation, as you're having only 1 output index; so index 0 is true per definition. Another issue could be your output activation function. It's made to create a binary decision boundary, nothing which aggregates for 3 classes. Lastly, `input` is a part of the in-built library. Please don't overwrite it.

Comment: @Uvar I've added an image of some info about the data.  
I'm not immidiately casting anything as int or float.  
I'll adjust the name for input, thank you!

Comment: The binary crossentropy as loss, as the name suggests, works for a 2-class problem, which you're not looking at. Let's see if I can find a resource.

Comment: can you try compiling the model with a `categorical_crossentropy` loss, 3 output nodes on the last Dense layer?

Comment: @Uvar After Mushfirat Mohaimin's previous suggestion of changing to tanh activation caused the output to always be -1. After changing to categorical_crossentropy loss and 3 output nodes on the last dense (x) layer (not hidden, since it wouldn't work) our training looks like this: `loss: nan - accuracy: 0.5020 - categorical_accuracy: 1.0000`

and predictions also output NaN

Comment: Use sparse_categorical_crossentropy, ensure that target is integer and add +1 to target column to make it >=0, make 3 output neurons and switch activation to softmax. Profit.

Answer (score 3):

`sigmoid` activation function can output a value between **0** & **1**
But you have labels **-1,0,1** which is not in the range **0** & **1**
Therefore, Using `tanh` activation function in the final `Dense` layer instead of `sigmoid` will work as `tanh` has a range of **-1** to **1**

Comment: That's huge, thank you! On first sight it appears that the strange loss is has changed to being around -0.24, but my accuracy is still at 0.50. I'll try running some predictions in a moment...

Answer (score 0):

I didn't end up finding a solution using Tensorflow.
I ended up using ML.net instead which works better for my situation since the rest of my application uses C#.
It was also beginner-friendly and make it easy to do exactly what i wanted to do.

This isn't the solution for everyone but if someone else reads this, maybe it's useful in your situation too.